# Unable to take screenshot of correct window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

This code is for screenshot capture, but this code not getting a desirable output. I am unable to take a screenshot of correct window. My code initializes a new Chrome driver, but does not get a screenshot of that window, which is what I require.

```
/----------------------------------take screenshot class--------------------------------/        
public class ScreenCapture {
    SendMailUsingAuthentication SMUA = new SendMailUsingAuthentication ();

        public void takeScreenShot() throws IOException, MessagingException   {
            String timeStamp;
            File screenShotName;
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                //The below method will save the screen shot in d drive with name "screenshot.png"
                timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); 
                screenShotName = new File("D:\\Manzelinc\\SNST_test_Auto\\Manzel"+timeStamp+".png");
                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, screenShotName);
                    SMUA.postMail(SendMailUsingAuthentication.emailList, SendMailUsingAuthentication.emailSubjectTxt, SendMailUsingAuthentication.emailMsgTxt, SendMailUsingAuthentication.emailFromAddress);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 

/----------------------------Listener class---------------------------------------------------------/
public class ReportGeneration implements ITestListener, IReporter  {
WebDriver driver;
SendMailUsingAuthentication SMUA = new SendMailUsingAuthentication ();

public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
     System.out.println("Start Of Execution(TEST)->"+arg0.getName());
}
public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
    System.out.println("Test Started->"+arg0.getName());
}
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
    System.out.println("Test Pass->"+arg0.getName());
}
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
    System.out.println("Test Failed->"+arg0.getName());
    //take Screenshot------------------------
    ScreenCapture SC = new ScreenCapture();
        try {
            SC.takeScreenShot();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Reporter.log("<br> <img src=.\\screenshots\\Untitled.png /> <br>");
    Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(null);
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new driver with `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`. You need to use the driver which is used for the actual tests.

Comment: You should pass your driver to `takeScreenShot()` method instead of creating a new WebDriver instance or make your driver static. There should be only one WebDriver instance in whole project.